# Find read-host value in file list

Tags: powershell

I have now moved on to automating IDRAC.  My script below will look at a list of servernames and IDRAC IP's.  I would like to have a user enter a single Servername "S0000A01PX' or whatever and have it search in a master list for the server IDRAC IP.  Right now, the script as it is opens every server's virtual console in the list.  I just need it to select only the user entry.  How do I have this search the file, find the IP next to the user entered servername, and open only the IDRAC for that servername?

example of what's in the CSV

```
computername    iPiDRAC
S0000A01PX  10.122.2.11
```

Script

```psh
$machinename = ""
$file = Import-Csv 'c:\temp\powershell\Branch Server IDRAC.csv'
$filelength = $file.length
$machine = Read-Host 'What is your Server?'
foreach ($line in $file){
    $DRACip = $line.iPiDRAC
    $DRACpw=cscript c:\PassGen1.vbs $machinename
    $DRACpw=$DRACpw[3]
    $DRACip
    $machinename
    $DRACPW
    $openIDRAC="http://"+$DRACip+"/console"
    $openIDRAC
    start $openIDRAC
    write-host "----------"
}
```

Comment: This requires knowledge of your CSV file structure. If there is a host name, you can query `$line.hostname` and compare it to `$machine` (in fact, filter the `$file` list for those objects that match, instead of running foreach and then check).

Comment: Do you want it to open multiples? The user could type in something that would match more than one server. Does it have to match exactly?

Comment: That would be useful actually, but I would like to figure out for one for now.  How would I implement say -contains?  Once I figure out how to search a file list, more possibilities open up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to have a general match and return launch all DRACs that match a simple change can get you there. `Where-Object{$_.computername -match $machine}`

```
$machinename = ""
$file = Import-Csv 'c:\temp\powershell\Branch Server IDRAC.csv'
$machinename = Read-Host 'What is your Server?'

$file | Where-Object{$_.computername -match $machinename} |ForEach-Object{
    $DRACip = $_.iPiDRAC
    $DRACpw=cscript c:\PassGen1.vbs $machinename
    $DRACpw=$DRACpw[3]
    $DRACip
    $machinename
    $DRACPW
    $openIDRAC="http://"+$DRACip+"/console"
    $openIDRAC
    start $openIDRAC
    write-host "----------"
}
```

You are mixing output and write-host which could get you into trouble so I would remove some of that extra fluff which I will assume is just there for testing. I don't see where you are using `$DRACpw` or `$machinename` unless that is somehow what you need to see in order to sign into the DRAC

Comment: I should probably use write-output, but yes, I do need to copy and paste the server name and password into the browser.  I wish I could pass that info, i suppose http://username:password/ip/console no longer works.  I wish I could open Virtual Console through SSH (PuTTY), but that's not possible either (but SSH is useful for quick POWERUP and other serveractions)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a bit of Where-Object.

For this CSV file:

```
computername,iPiDRAC
S0000A01PX,10.122.2.11
```

Import the file as you have been:

```
$file = Import-Csv 'c:\temp\powershell\Branch Server IDRAC.csv'
```

Ask your question:

```
$machine = Read-Host 'What is your Server?'
```

Look for the server name in your $file array, which will output an object representing that line in the CSV, then get its iPiDRAC property:

```
($file | Where-Object {$_.computername -eq $machine}).iPiDRAC
10.122.2.11
```